# Is there a way to rename a follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a follower titled 'Dark Brotherhood Initiate'.

Is there a console command to enable me to giver her a proper name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I have found, you cannot do it via a console command.  You will need a mod to [rename a NPC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGA42ej5JRo).

You can download it [from Skyrim Nexus](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4554).

> Steps

> 1. Edit a NPC in Skyrim NPC Editor
> 2. Save to .esp file
> 3. Open TESsnip and open the .esp you just made
> 4. Double click EDID and click where the name is and type what you want
>    for the name of the NPC
> 5. Now click on the Hex numbers to the left and put 00 at the end then
>    click save at the bottom
> 6. Double click FULL and Repeat step 4-5
> 7. Now save your .esp as what you named your NPC example: Test.esp
> 8. Put the .esp in your Data folder in your skyrim directory then laumch the game
>    and see your new renamed NPC

> NOTE: When renaming a NPC make sure you scroll down
> the list to see if their name is there then rename it to what you want
> example: scroll down the list where EDID is and see if anyone of them has a name just look to the top right if its in mixed letters then dont edit it just the name if its there like in FULL and EDID

Comment: Wow. Thanks for finding this out. After reading your instructions I am not sure now wether to do this or not. I thought it would be quite easy or not possible. If you renamed a important character - wouldn't that mess up some of the quest scripts ? For example 'Dark Brotherhood Initiate' is not really specific. Hey thanks again for the info.

Comment: @Terry No. Quest scripts don't care about the silly human-readable names we give each other, just the barcodes tattooed in the NPCs' digital DNA.

Answer (score 1):

The [Jaxonz Renamer](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/57335/) mod makes renaming **way** faster and less tedious than using console commands.

Answer (score 0):

An option you have, on computer, is the [Extensible Follower Framework mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/12933).

With this extension, you can rename your follower, without directly accessing the **`.esp`** files.